# Pandas qcut ValueError: Input array must be 1 dimensional

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, quantile

I was trying to categorize my values into 10 bins and I met with this error. How can I avoid this error and bin them smoothly?

Attached are samples of the data and code.

Data

```
JPM
2008-01-02  NaN
2008-01-03  NaN
2008-01-04  NaN
2008-01-07  NaN
2008-01-08  NaN
... ...
2009-12-24  -0.054014
2009-12-28  0.002679
2009-12-29  -0.030015
2009-12-30  -0.019058
2009-12-31  -0.010090

505 rows × 1 columns
```

Code

```
group_names = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
discretized_roc = pd.qcut(df, 10, labels=group_names)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass column `JPM` and for only integer indicators of the bins use `labels=False`:

```
discretized_roc = pd.qcut(df['JPM'], 10, labels=False)
```

If need first column instead label use [`DataFrame.iloc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html):

```
discretized_roc = pd.qcut(df.iloc[:, 0], 10, labels=False)
```

Comment: are there ways to do it without quoting 'JPM'?